# ThinkingSphinx indexing ActsAsTaggable Model.tag_counts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

In order to assign tags, users of my software search their existing tags (which is populated in an autocomplete). I want to index this search in Sphinx so the tag search is ultra responsive. I have seen posts on how to [index a Model's tags with sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082399/thinking-sphinx-and-acts-as-taggable-on-plugin) which helps when trying to find all the objects with that tag name, but I want to index the tag search itself for people searching for existing tags.

I am trying to use Sphinx for this search

> Lead.tag_counts(:conditions =>
>   ["tags.name like ?", 'accounting%'])

Which produces the SQL

> SELECT tags.id, tags.name, COUNT(*) AS count FROM `tags` LEFT
>   OUTER JOIN taggings ON tags.id =
>   taggings.tag_id AND taggings.context =
>   'tags' INNER JOIN leads ON leads.id =
>   taggings.taggable_id WHERE
>   ((taggings.taggable_type = 'Lead' AND
>   tags.name like 'accounting%' )) GROUP
>   BY tags.id, tags.name HAVING COUNT(*)
>
> > 0

I assume I have to add indexes to the Tag model to allow the below to work, but not quite sure what they should be.

> Tag.sphinx_leads_scope.search(params[:tag])

Thanks, John-Paul

Answer (score 0):

Given `acts-as-taggable-on` has its own Tag class, this gets a little tricky, but if you put this code somewhere (perhaps in an initializer?), I think it should work - though it's untested:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.define_index do
  indexes name
end
```

Adding a sphinx scope is trickier - you'd need to monkeypatch ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag for that. Definitely not out of the question, though. You also may want to add a filter for taggable type via taggings... although string filters are very limited - make sure you [read the docs](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/common_issues.html#string_filters). Also, if you are going down the string filter path, you'll end up with possibly multiple tagging types for a tag, and so you'll want to concatenate the CRC32'd values with commas... check out [this somewhat related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339333/searching-with-thinking-sphinx-and-filtering-results/4341754#4341754) (for the code snippets).